# Vue por que no se me oculta el modal con v-if

Tags: vue.js

Quiero ocultar el modal cuando pulse el botón si estoy probando con `v-if`, pero no se me cambia el valor al pulsar el botón y se me queda en `true`.

```
div v-if="cerrar = true" class="modal-content"
```

```
<div v-if="cerrar = true" class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Eres mayor de 18 años?</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button @click="cerrar = false" type="button" class="botonsi" data-dismiss="modal">SI</button>
    <button @click="cerrar = true" type="button" class="botonno" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
    {{$data}}
  </div>
</div>

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      cerrar: false,
    };
  },
}
```

Comment: Si escribes `cerrar = true`, le estás asignado el valor `true` a `cerrar`, si en cambio escribes `cerrar === true` estás comparando el valor que tenga `cerrar` con `true`. En fin, tendrías que hacer una comparaciín para el condicional `v-if` y no una asignación de valor. Por otro lado bastaría con `v-if="cerrar"` que es lo mismo que `v-if="true"` o `v-if="false"` según el valor que tenga `cerrar` en ese momento

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración.